# Sink from Delta Live Table to Kafka, initial sink works, but any subsequent updates fail

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a DLT pipeline that ingests a topic from my kafka stream, transforms it into a DLT, then I wish to write that table back into Kafka under a new topic.

So far, I have this working, however it only works on first load of the table, then after any subsequent updates will crash my read and write stream.

My DLT tables updates correctly, so I see updates from my pipeline into the Gold table,

```
CREATE OR REFRESH LIVE TABLE deal_gold1
TBLPROPERTIES ("quality" = "gold")
COMMENT "Gold Deals"
AS SELECT
  documentId,
  eventTimestamp,
  substring(fullDocument.owner_id, 11, 24) as owner_id,
  fullDocument.owner_type as owner_type,
  substring(fullDocument.account_id, 11, 24) as account_id,
  substring(fullDocument.manager_account_id, 11, 24) as manager_account_id,
  fullDocument.hubspot_deal_id as hubspot_deal_id,
  fullDocument.stage as stage,
  fullDocument.status as status,
  fullDocument.title as title
  FROM LIVE.deal_bronze_cleansed
```

but then when I try to read from it via a separate notebook, these updates cause it to crash

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
# this one is the problem not the write stream
df = spark.readStream.format("delta").table("deal_stream_test.deal_gold1")

display(df)

writeStream= (
  df
  .selectExpr("CAST(documentId AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/benperram21/checkpoint")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluentBootstrapServers)
  .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret))
  .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
  .option("topic", confluentTopicName)
  .start()
)
```

I was looking and can see this might be as a result of it not being read as "Append". But yeah any thoughts on this? Everything works upset updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now DLT doesn't support output to the arbitrary sinks.  Also, all Spark operations should be done inside the nodes of the execution graph (functions labeled with `dlt.table` or `dlt.view`).

Right now the workaround would be to run that notebook outside of the DLT pipeline, as a separate task in the multitask job (workflow).